# Firebase data structure and rules advice

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have just started developing my first app and have never used Firebase in the past. Before I get too far in to development I would like some advice on how to structure my Firebase data and rules.

The structure/rules need to allow users to upload their own posts, only the owner can update or delete their own posts and posts can be viewed both as a complete list or as a list of posts from the selected user.

A user can also set a post as a favourite, again only they can add or remove a favourite but other users can view a users favourites.

Below is the data structure so far:

```
{
   users:{
     'userId1':{  //Firebase assigned ID
       'name': "user1",
       'email': "user@email.com",
     },
     'userId2':{
       'name': "user2",
       'email': "user2@email.com",
     }
   },
   posts:{
     'postsId1':{  //Firebase assigned ID
       'title': "title",
       'message': "message text",
       'userId': "userId1"
     },
     'postsId2':{  
       'title': "title2",
       'message': "message text",
       'userId' : "userId1"
     },
   },
   'favourites': {
     'userId1': {
                'postsId1': "note about favourite",
                'postsId2': "note about favourite"
      }
      'userId2': {
                'postsId2': "note about favourite"
      }
   }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You try study these things [Firebase Database Structure](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s) or [NOSQL DATA MODELING TECHNIQUES](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/) and [Structure Your Database for firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data)

Comment: Thanks for the links they were very helpful. The main points seem to be to keep data flat but structure it based around the required data to minimise requests.